# Is this C++11 atomic_thread_fence call the appropriate replacement for this legacy function?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

One of my programs contains some old code for implementing a memory barrier using OS/compiler specific APIs; it looks like this:

```
inline void memory_barrier()
{
#if defined(ATOMIC_APPLE)
  OSMemoryBarrier();
#elif defined(ATOMIC_NEWER_MSC_VER)
  _ReadWriteBarrier();
#elif defined(ATOMIC_NEWER_GNUC)
  __sync_synchronize();
#else
# error "no memory barrier implemented for this platform"
#endif
}
```

... however, the APIs called by this function are non-portable, and also they cause "deprecated function" warnings to appear in my compile output, so I'd like to replace them with something from the C++11 standard library instead.  After some googling, I came up with this as a potential replacement:

```
inline void memory_barrier()
{
   std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

My question is, is this new function a logically equivalent replacement for the old one?  Or do I need something different in order to keep the same semantics as before?

Comment: There are 3 levels here - (1) how the compiler sees the code in terms of optimisation/reorganisation; (2) in-process/thread synchronisation; (3) cross-process synchronisation.  Which of these do the existing (deprecated) call do?

Comment: I believe the intent was 1 and 2.

Comment: Show us what the old functions did: official documentation, unofficial explanation, or asm.

Comment: @curiousguy There are no docs AFAICT :( Here's a snippet from an `atomic.h` header showing it being used to implement an atomic_int class:  `public:
    operator int() const {memory_barrier(); return value;}
    void operator = (int v) {value = v; memory_barrier();}

  private:
    mutable volatile int value;`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I can't see the effect of a barrier in that code. What prevents writing to `value` from being reordered by the compiler (WRT previous non volatile writes) or CPU (WRT all writes), and WRT previous reads? What prevents the reading of `value` from being reordered WRT to later memory operations?

Comment: @curiousguy I tend to agree; I didn't write the code and I suspect it may be incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of the non-portable methods your old code used, short answer: the C++11 code will *safely* replace all of the previous functions.

However, `std::atomic_thread_fence` will both be a compiler barrier (disallowing the compiler to reorder instructions across the barrier) as well as a CPU barrier for that given thread (disallowing the CPU to reorder instructions across the barrier). The previous methods you've used don't actually have exactly the same semantics.

- `_ReadWriteBarrier` (Windows) is just a barrier for the compiler and **not** a barrier for the CPU
- `OSMemoryBarrier` (macOS) is actually a direct replacement for `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`. And it's deprecated btw.
- `__sync_synchronize` (GCC) is also a direct replacement for `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.

If you just want a barrier for the compiler (e.g. the current Windows version of the code), you can use [std::atomic_signal_fence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_signal_fence) instead of std::atomic_thread_fence.

Since the old code wasn't completely clear on what its intention is, I'd personally err more on the side of caution and use the `std::atomic_thread_fence` you've suggested (and **not** the compiler-only barrier), because I suspect that the original code on Windows was actually conceptually wrong (and it just happened to work by accident). This could technically impact performance slightly, depending on how this was used previously, but only go to a compiler-only fence if you are **really** sure that that is semantically correct.

A small other remark, because I saw it in the old code you were replacing: you had a check `#elif defined(ATOMIC_NEWER_MSC_VER)` in there to check for MSVC on Windows. I've seen this a lot, and I think this makes software far less portable to other compilers, since most other compilers on Windows (such as MinGW) also provide most of the intrinsic functions in their own headers, so I don't recommend detecting Windows via `#ifdef`s for the MSVC compiler, but rather via platform macros (e.g. `#ifdef _WIN32`). Only check for the MSVC compiler for actual compiler features that aren't provided by other compilers, such as `#pragma comment(lib, ...)`. (In this case this doesn't matter since you are replacing the old code with portable C++11 code, which is great, but in case you run across that in the rest of your codebase.)

Comment: Note that MSVC only defines `_ReadWriteBarrier()` for x86 and "x64", where it's equivalent to `std::atomic_thread_fence(acq_rel)`.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readwritebarrier?view=msvc-170).  A compiler-only barrier gives you whatever ordering the underlying hardware memory model gives.  On x86 and x86-64, that's program-order plus a store buffer (StoreLoad reordering) with store forwarding.  That's why an `acq_rel` fence compiles to zero instructions on x86(-64)

Comment: interesting question and interesting answer. I'm a concurrency hobbist for many years now and this answer has really thought me some new things!

Answer (score 2):

MSVC's `_ReadWriteBarrier()` is the weakest of the three, but apparently sufficient for your code's use-case.  So it only needs an acquire/release fence, not blocking [StoreLoad reordering](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/):

```
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
```

This compiles to zero instructions on x86(-64), because the underlying hardware memory model is program order plus a store buffer with store-forwarding.  (StoreLoad reordering plus seeing your own stores without waiting for them to become globally visible.)

As @chris_se pointed out, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readwritebarrier?view=msvc-170) for `_ReadWriteBarrier()` describe it as only preventing [compile-time reordering](https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) (like GNU C `asm("" :: "memory)`), but they also say it's only available on x86 and "x64" (x86-64) where the hardware memory model makes it an acq/rel fence for inter-thread purposes on strongly-ordered ISAs, as well as being `atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst)` on all ISAs.

---

`__sync_synchronize()` is stronger than necessary (a full barrier), but until the [GNU C `__atomic` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) made the [`__sync` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) obsolete, it was **the only portable thing available that was strong *enough*.**

`std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)` in the `<atomic>` header (for GCC/clang) is implemented as `__atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`, a full barrier equivalent to `__sync_synchronize()`.

The other possible explanation is that this old code was buggy, with a barrier weaker than they intended on x86 Windows.  But most code doesn't need seq_cst operations or fences; [acquire and release](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) are sufficient for mutexes for example.

Still, with a function name like `memory_barrier`, most people would expect it to be a *full* barrier.  Perhaps `_ReadWriteBarrier()` instead of [Windows `MemoryBarrier()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-memorybarrier?source=recommendations) was an optimization because they know how their program used it?  Or perhaps unintentional but still happened to work because most programs don't need seq_cst.

---

If your code doesn't involve any `std::atomic<T>` or `std::atomic_flag` objects at all in your whole program, it's not formally guaranteed by ISO C++ that `atomic_thread_fence` will order one `volatile int*` access wrt. another for example.  (And you couldn't detect the difference in a program without data-race UB).

But a function can't know whether some caller might have used `relaxed` atomic operations that would be ordered wrt. earlier or later non-atomic operations by a fence, so compilers basically can't reorder non-atomic operations across fences either.

Current implementations certainly don't try to break fences, so it's basically fine to use `std::atomic_thread_fence` instead of `__atomic_thread_fence` or other implementation-specific fences that are defined to order all operations as a way to implement `std::atomic` semantics.

If you also plan to replace other parts of hand-rolled atomics with `std::atomic` types, then great, this is a non-issue.

You can also start turning things like `foo.load(relaxed); barrier();` into `foo.load(seq_cst)` or maybe just `foo.load(acquire)` if that's all that's needed.

On x86, seq_cst and acquire loads compile the same.  On newer AArch64, `ldapr` is somewhat cheaper as an acquire load than `ldar` which can't order with earlier `stlr` to give seq_cst semantics. It's definitely cheaper to do an acquire or SC load than to do a plain load and then an SC fence.

On x86, only `foo.store(value, seq_cst)` needs extra asm barrier instructions beyond what's already needed; SC loads are just `mov`, and any RMW is a full barrier.  So if you're looking to make things efficient, making pure stores just be `release` when possible is a good idea.  As well as of course folding `barrier(); store(relaxed)` into `store(release)`, if surrounding code didn't also rely on the barrier.

(See https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/ for details on the difference between a release *fence* vs. a release *operation*.)